# How to generate javadoc with puml diagrams?

Tags: gradle, build, javadoc, sequence-diagram

I am trying to generate my Javadoc with my sequence diagrams integrated using Gradle 8.0(7.2).

### my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"


mainClassName = 'com.twu.calculator.CalculatorApp'
group = 'calculator'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = "Calculator Console App"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.github.stefanbirkner:system-rules:1.16.1'
}

task renderPlantUml(type: RenderPlantUmlTask) {

}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.overview = "src/main/javadoc/overview.html" // relative to source root
    options.addStringOption("sourcepath","${projectDir}/src/main/javadoc")
}

javadoc.dependsOn renderPlantUml

// To execute the app
task runApp (type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes){
    /* Can pass all the properties: */
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    standardInput = System.in
    description = "Running the Calculator"
    main = "com.twu.calculator.CalculatorApp"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Right now the expected output is only accomplished on the second I run `gradle javadoc`being the sequence of steps the following one :

```
gradle renderPlantUml
gradle javadoc
```

This results in overview.html not finding the diagrams as in the picture bellow .

[overview.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNNv8.png)

Then I need to repeat the above commands so the expected output is the right one . See the picture below for reference .

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF5fq.png)

What do I need to change in my `build.gradle?`

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the Javadoc task to copy the files you want to include such as the images.

```
javadoc {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from('src/main/java')
            into("$buildDir/docs/javadoc/")
            include("**/doc-files/**/*")
        }
    }
}
```

Places your image(s) in the same package your class is in a folder named `doc-files/`

Then just include them in your Javadoc:

```
/**
 * <img src="doc-files/path/to/image.jpg">
 */
```

See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4046